# Como converter um valor numérico em boolean?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Recebo um valor `boolean` do banco de dados, no qual pretendo definir um `checkbox` dinamicamente. O valor recebido é `0` ou `1`. Tentei fazer desta forma abaixo:

```
var status = 1; //valor recebido
$("#status").prop('checked', status);
```

Porém de acordo [com a documentação do método prop](http://api.jquery.com/prop/), deve-se receber como parâmetro um `boolean` ou uma função, e não um numeral.

Como faço para converter um valor numérico em `boolean`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se tiver certeza que a entrada é `int` pode aplicar diretamente 0 ou 1 para o `.checked = status;` (mesmo que `.prop('checked', status)`) (como o @Sergio explicou):

```
var status = 1; //valor recebido

$("#status").prop('checked', status);
```

Mas para outros casos aonde não exista a conversão automática você usar assim com `!!`, desde que tenha certeza de ser um `int`:

```
var status = 1; //valor recebido

$("#status").prop('checked', !!status);
```

Ou assim usando "operador ternário":

```
var status = 1; //valor recebido

$("#status").prop('checked', status ? true : false);
```

Agora se não tiver certeza de estar recebendo um estiver recebendo `string` pode checar assim:

```
var status = '1'; //valor recebido

$("#status").prop('checked', status == '1');
```

---

Se quiser apenas "converter" inteiros para booleanos:

```js
var status = 1;

console.log('Com ==', status == '1'); //Este talvez seja o mais garantido
console.log('Com !!', !!status);
console.log('Com ternário', status ? true : false);
```

Comment: Não é preciso `!!` ele é convertido em booleano [mesmo com JavaScript nativo](https://jsfiddle.net/wnj3qwj0/).

Comment: @Sergio Para `.prop()` ou `.checked = 1` você está correto, a questão  que apontei isto para qualquer situações aonde não haja a conversão "automática", para duvidas semelhantes (é que eu me foquei no titulo).

Comment: Não seria melhor forçar o int usando `!!parseInt(status)`, porque se for `string` vai resultar em `true` em ambos os casos. :S

Comment: @Inkeliz sim, no caso do 1 e do 2, mas como o AP tinha colocado um `var status = 1;` presumi que a entrada seria sempre `int` e outra eu segui o titulo, mas vou adicionar uma explicação melhor.

Answer (score 2):

testa o *tipo* dessa variável primeiro. Caso seja string vai dar sempre verdadeiro. Verifica com:

```
console.log(typeof status, status);
```

Para ter a certeza usa `Number(status)`, ou `status == '1' ? true : false`.

```
$("#status").prop('checked', status == '1' ? true : false);
```

Exemplos:

```js
var status = '1';
$('#statusA').prop('checked', Number(status));
$('#statusB').prop('checked', status == '1' ? true : false);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="statusA" type="checkbox">
<input id="statusB" type="checkbox">
<input id="status_controle" type="checkbox">
```

Answer (score 0):

Eu muito provavelmente faria algo assim:

var status = 1; // valor recebido

$("#status").prop('checked', Number(status) ? true : false);

Usando ternária mesmo, e convertendo o valor sempre em um Number, no caso de vir um valor acima de 0 seria true e caso contrário seria false.